# Cordova viewEnter event like the ionic one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

For some direction choices I doesn't manage, my team need to use Cordova and not Ionic.

We need to refresh some datas each time that a view is opened but it seems that everything is in cache so we can't refresh...

In Ionic there is an $ionicView.enter what does everything we search for...
Is there a way to reproduce this event in pure Cordova ?

Thanks for help !

Comment: What framework do you use for UI?

Comment: No framework. Just Cordova and Angular.